# Cameras with Android Operating Systems

Tags: camera, gps, wifi

Can someone please help me. I need to find a camera or info about cameras with built in GPS, touchscreen, Wifi, and Android 6.0 or higher (preferably Oreo) OS operating system. I am a property inspector and have used the Samsung Galaxy 2 for the last 6 years. I can no longer use it because the app I have to use to take photos (InspectorAde) now requires at least an Android 6.0 or higher OS. I was recommended to  use a new phone. I tried it and it is horrible. Need a designated camera similar to what I had, not a phone. I cannot find a list anywhere that includes cameras operating systems. Most cameras don't even list their operating systems in their specs. Please help me.

I need a dedicated camera that has a zoom lense of at least x10 preferably x20, gps (all photos have to be GEO tagged for location), a touchscreen (preferably at least 4-5 inches), wifi, and has to have an android operating system of 6.0 or higher to use the app that I am required to take my photos with.

To answer some of your questions: I cant use my current camera any longer because the app I have to use to take my photos with (InspectorAde) now requires an android 6.0 or higher operating system, my current camera is an older/lower version operating system. What was horrible- slow, uncomfortable, inefficient, etc. I have to take many photos quickly. 8-10 hours a day. Holding it alone is very uncomfortable and actually hurts after 2-3 hours of use. phones are not designed to fit in your hands in the position to take pics, There is great risk of dropping a 400 phone, no wrist straps available. It is not able to zoom clear enough to take a photo of address numbers on properties i cannot enter and must take from public right of way. To use the touchscreen zoom is very clumsy and time consuming instead of having a designated zoom button in the natural position of your hand/fingers as a camera would have. These are just a few reasons. The new phone I tried by recommendation was the moto z3 play, with the Hasselblad zoomx10 Moto Mod. The mod slows down the camera and there is about a 6 -9 second delay after each photo.

Comment: "used the Samsung Galaxy 2" ..... "Need a designated camera similar to what I had".... These two statements are inconsistent. I may be wrong, but I don't think there are any Android camera-only devices out there. But, pretty much any modern Samsung tablet or phone runs Android (there are other manufacturers, too) and meets all your other conditions other than "not a phone" (well, the tablet meets that condition, too). Most, if not all, actual dedicated cameras use the manufacturers proprietary firmware/software - generally not even what could be called a full operating system.

Comment: is there a reason you can't just continue to use the app version that worked?

Comment: I suggest getting a new phone that works for you. You didn't specify what was 'horrible' about what you tried, but there are many options to choose from. If you don't actually want/need the phone functionality then don't activate it.

Comment: Which new phone specifically did you try and find not to be acceptable?  In what way was it bad?  Many new phones have excellent cameras, but not all of them -- it's possible a different new phone would get the job done for you.

Comment: To answer some of your questions: I cant use my current camera any longer because the app I have to use to take my photos with (InspectorAde) now requires an android 6.0 or higher operating system, my current camera is an older/lower version operating system. What was horrible- slow, uncomfortable, inefeccient, etc. I have to take many photos quickly. 8-10 hours a day. Holding it alone is very uncomfortable and actually hurts after 2-3 hours of use. phones are not designed to fit in your hands in the position to take pics, There is great risk of dropping a 400 phone, no wriststraps available.

Comment: Does your app require that the photos be taken on the same device, or is it possible to take photos on something else, transfer the files and then use them in that app?  Because I think the exact device you're looking for -- a proper camera running Android -- doesn't exist, but there are lots of solutions for transferring photos from a proper camera to an android device.

Comment: The hand ergonomics and lanyard problems could potentially be solved with something like this: https://just-mobile.com/products/shuttergrip

Comment: And there are others as well: https://wiki.ezvid.com/best-smartphone-camera-grips

Comment: You could potentially combine that with something like this to get you the reach you need.  The quality may not be amazing but if all you need to do is read numbers from a distance it's probably fine: https://www.amazon.com/CoPedvic-Samsung-Android-Telephoto-Telescope/dp/B07WBZNYNF/

Comment: Presumably you were using the Samsung Galaxy Camera 2? Don't know if there is any newer equivalent.

Comment: Thank you Nate for your help, I appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: Did your phone that you used for the last six years have a 10X zoom lens?

Comment: @MichaelC That Galaxy Camera 2 has a 21x optical zoom (and isn't a phone).

Comment: I was going to suggest yongnuo yn450 https://www.cinema5d.com/yongnuo-yn450-m43-mirrorless-camera-with-android/ but while it was supposed to be availible last year it is not for sale anywhere, will ask a separate question and see if anyone knows what happend.

Comment: @vclaw Thanks. I wasn't aware of that.

Answer (score 2):

Cameras with Android have mostly vanished again. The mix between a camera and a phone (mostly combining the negatives of two worlds like high battery use and clunky cases) has not really worked.

There seems to be an "interesting" product by a chinese company. The Yongnuo YN450. M43 Sensor (whouch would be pretty neat), EF-Mount (which seems a bit odd, since EF lenses need a backfocus distance of around 40mm. Images show, that it seems to have an "extension" protruding from the body). The upside of "EF Mount" is clearly the huge array of lenses available. The downside is, that it won't fit in your pocket! They say, that it should sell for around 500$

It's probably really hard to find this camera. But getting a phone with a good camera is not that hard anymore.

And than there is the Zeiss ZX1. Another really special camera with a full frame sensor, fixed lens and a price tag that will be around 5000$.

Both of those cameras run android and should have been released but have not really materialized on the market until now.

Answer (score 2):

The Android requirement is what makes this impossible. Camera makers have tried in attempt at novelty but it failed due to inefficiency. Android is much heavier than necessary which drains battery life that is already short on cameras, not to mention startup time. Also, a screen that large is hard to fit on a camera because there are a lot more buttons and controls that make it easier to operate. The few that were made with large screens did it at the expense of controls which is not desirable.

Technically Zeiss just released another attempt at an [Android based camera](https://www.zeiss.com/consumer-products/int/photography/zx1.html) and although it is expected to make extremely high-quality images, it will have the same issues discussed. Plus, it's a $6000 USD camera and has a fixed lens which is unsuitable for real-estate photography.

Once you remove the Android and excessively large screen requirement, you are left with a few options. If you do a search on my website for a [current digital camera with a GPS and Ultra Zoom](https://www.neocamera.com/search_camera.php?ultrazoom=1&gps=1&by=feature), you get 3 results:

- Nikon Coolpix P900
- Nikon Coolpix P950
- Sony Cybershot HX90V

The first two are larger models with a good grip and plenty of controls which improve ergonomics but they may get tiresome if you carry them for hours at a time. The Sony is much smaller and lighter but it still packs a long zoom and a builtin EVF. All these cameras will produce very similar image quality since they have their sensor size is the same and resolution is similar.

Another possibility is to consider a camera without a GPS but that can get GPS info tagged via an accessory or a Bluetooth link. This does significantly lower battery-life though and both your phone and camera need to last sufficiently long to have all images tagged as they are taken.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're in a bind given the requirements. Could you list out what you need exactly? The GPS feature is available on many SLRs (but drains your battery), and is available on many P&S cameras. I don't believe you'll find a single SLR running android, nor will you find a Point and Shoot. Instead you'll be stuck on android phones.

The GPS information can be added to a photo later (tagging).

Luminix makes cameras that are decent for battery life, but before recommending a single brand its important to know what contractual requirements you have for what you're asking. You might not need what you think you do.

Comment: I need a dedicated camera that has a zoom lense of at least x10 preferably x20, gps (all photos have to be GEO tagged for location), a touchscreen (preferably at least 4-5 inches), wifi, and has to have an android operating system of 6.0 or higher to use the app that I am required to take my photos with.

Comment: Gotcha. So the 'have to use' is a hard and fast requirement for your job. Are you an independent contractor or is your phone part of your company profile?

You aren't going to find a phone with that zoom, and I'm not conversant about the app to know more. Let me see if I can get some free time to loo kat it for a go.

Comment: Thank you, your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Thank you very much for your assistance/time, it is very much appreciated.I am an independent contractor.

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but I am fairly confident no dedicated camera uses Android.

Two major reasons:

1)All major camera manufacturers were in existence quite some time before Android OS came out.

Therefore they developed their own specialized OSes for the specific devices they make.

Android instead is a *general-purpose operating system* (although targeted mostly at mobile devices).

2) No dedicated camera manufacturer would go to the trouble of basing their device on a  general purpose OS, since it would contain so much dead weight features. Which could also break. Plus, it would run much slower. And unless using some RTOS -- unpredictably slower at any particular moment.

So, your best bet would be to use a dedicated camera with a Bluetooth/NFC connection to  your phone, for automatic upload of photos to phone, and have on the phone that software you need access existing gallery images rather than phone's camera.

If that is not possible, the only alternative is a better mobile phone. Some of them are reasonably better at taking pictures and might even have optical zoom.

Comment: IIRC many sony models ARE android based internally - but they do not present it to you as a generic android device.

Comment: @rackandboneman even if they are, they should be stripped-down versions and I would be very surprised if they didn't go for adding real-time features as well as probably not following original Android updates. There is a difference between Android-based and Android-compatible.

Comment: At least Nikon has had models with android. But the idea never really took off. There are probably 2 reasons:
1. Phones have become much better at taking good images and have much shorter product cycles than digital cameras have
2. The downsides of combining the two outwigh the upsides (weight, battery use...)

Comment: @kruemi I be would think pure stock Android is not really well suited for a device such as a camera, because it is not a real time operating system. A RTOS is built in such a way that it generally can guarantee a task finishing within specific time. General purpose OSes are usually not RTOS. Would you care for a DSLR that might finish shooting your picture in any unpredictable time between shutter time and say 10 secs?

Comment: @Gnudiff it depends on what you expect. Yes, stock android is not realtime, but in most cases that's not needed. For user interaction it just has to be "fast enough". And even on my cheapo phone android is responsive enough. You're probably not going to get <100ms shutter lag. But honestly...

Comment: @kruemi "that's not needed" is not something I would apply to a dedicated digital camera responsiveness. Also cost. I suspect that chipsets that could easily rum Android are an order more expensive than the ones actually inside DSLRs and P&S devices.

Comment: Canon uses its own RTOS, which replaced a previously used VxWorks RTOS. This book claims most digital cameras do use RTOS https://books.google.lv/books?id=3w_XeZ2px6oC&pg=PA45&lpg=PA45&dq=are+digital+cameras+running+rtos&source=bl&ots=C2vLiTkonp&sig=ACfU3U1wHIReXnZNsl6xKqcCQWYP--3qsA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi8veTYk6vqAhVLpYsKHX6wAHQQ6AEwAHoECAMQAQ#v=onepage&q=are%20digital%20cameras%20running%20rtos&f=false

Comment: I know, this is getting WAY offtopic. But don't fall for the misconception that "RT" means "fast" in any way. It doesn't. It just means that you'll get a guaranteed answer within a guaranteed time (hard realtime). But the cycle time of a RT system can be arbritararily long... btw: DOS is a realtime capable OS ;)

Comment: @kruemi I know, you're quite right about speed. but guaranteed time is what is important here. a camera has certain technical performance parameters, many of which are time-based. burst shot speed for example. what is the point of moving from a 3 shot/s camera to 6 one, if that 6 is really, well, 2-10ish?  RTOS in cameras still gets swamped by changing environment, but at least in similar environments you can  rely on certain performance.